# htaccess redirect subdomain AND subdirectory to external url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory, external-url

I want redirect:

`http://cbpq.luisgustavoventura.com/`
AND
`http://luisgustavoventura.com/cbpq/`

to:

`http://cbpq.org.br/`

i tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(cbpq\.luisgustavoventura\.com|luisgustavoventura\.com/cbpq)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.cbpq.org.br/$1 [L,R]
```

but doesn't work.

Please, suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `/cbpq` using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. It is better to keep these as 2 separate rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^luisgustavoventura\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cbpq(/.*)?$ http://www.cbpq.org.br$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cbpq\.luisgustavoventura\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cbpq.org.br/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```